# ODE problem with an integral on one side.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(f(x))^2=\int_{0}^xf(t)dt$$
I have this ODE problem in my textbook, the question is to find all $f(x), (x>0)$. I do realize that the left side of the equation is the derivation of the right side (obviously squared). However, I found my self stuck after this.
I tried to assign the integral as $U(x)$, and so the ODE that I got is :
$(U(x)')^2=u(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we find all the absolutely continuous functions $f$. By taking the derivative at both sides we have
$$
2f(x)f'(x)=f(x)
$$
hence we have $f(x)(1-2f'(x))=0$, so if $f(x)\neq 0$ then $2f'(x)=1$, which means $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x+\mathrm{constant}$ for some region $\{x\geq C\} $. Therefore the space of solutions can be described by the set
$$
S=\left\{f\in\mathrm{AC} (0,\infty )\vert f(x)=0\ \text{for }x\leq C,\ f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x-\frac{1}{2} C\ \text{for } x\geq C\right\}
$$
Since $S$ is closed under the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty } $, this is the set of all solutions to this integral equation.

Comment: Integration constant must be determined by substituting the integrated solution with explicit constant back into the original equation. Here it just happens to be zero, but it need not have been

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Yes, I just skip this.

Comment: This answer is wrong. $f(x) \notequiv 0$ does  not give you $2f'(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In the smooth case it must be. But there does exists solutions that are not smooth and not contained in this answer. I will give a modification.

Comment: Now it looks fine. $+1$ from me.

Comment: If continuity of $f$ is not required, you could switch the sign of a solution on any set of measure zero and still satisfy the original integral equation.